# Is there a way to implement a LinkedList with multiple child-nodes in Java?

Tags: java, list, graph, collections

I am trying to implement a package-system which is commonly present in object-oriented programming language:

[image]

But I am not really sure which datastructure I am supposed to use, I thought about a directed graph at first. Nethertheless I think that some kind of LinkedList, which allows the addition of multiple childnodes would be a better and easier solution.
At least I guess so....
Can someone please tell me **which datastructure may be the best solution for my problem?**

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you describe to us what your problem is!

Comment: Seems like a non-binary tree for me.

Comment: This is a tree. (In this case, it happens to be a binary tree since no node has more than two child nodes. Pck 1 is the only node with 2, all others have 1 or 0.)

Comment: See How to ask a question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  There usually trade offs, small storage or fast ... . There is no "BEST", it depends on the details of the problem.

Comment: Java package imports don't work in a tree fashion.  If you import java.util.* it'll sort out the fully-resolved class names of its direct children, but you still have to import child packages individually.

Comment: @duffymo Where is the problem with that? In this case, the wildcard `*` means `all direct children`.

Comment: You're asking to use structure 'X' to implement structure 'Y', but structure 'Y' exists as a thing by itself: a Tree.

Comment: @dan1st - import java.util.* does not mean that all the classes in java.util.concurrent are sorted.  You have to do java.util.concurrent.* independently.  Same for all child packages.  Only direct child classes are imported.

Comment: This is literally what I said: all **direct** children

Comment: First, there was no mention of any correlation between what the OP wants to do and the package import system of java.  Nor did the OP ever imply anything about the Java import structure.   So unless folks are psychic, the OP  simply used the term package to describe the children in the (possibly non-binary) tree structure.  But even if that is what the OP wants tp recreate, a non-binary tree structure of classes does exist in the API and there is nothing wrong with modeling that in ones own structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a nonbinary tree like this:

```java
public class Pck{
    private List<Pck> children;
    private Pck parent;//optional
    private String name;//optional
    //Also include a variable for your data
}
```

Each package has a reference to each subpackage.

If you want to get the name of a specific package, you would also need to maintain references to the parent package (and the name of each package within its layer). You could iterate over the parent to the next parent etc. and build the name.

Similarily, you could get the concrete package by splitting the name and recursively finding the next child.